# Ember Routes Without hashtag

Tags: ember.js

I have the follow JS code to my ember.js app.

```
Beers.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('beers', {path: "/beers"}, function(){
    this.route('all');
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

The problem is, I only can access using domain/#/beers/all. Reading the ember.js documentation I try use this:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

But don't works too. I would like to access using the following url: domain/beers/all

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct way of doing it. However when using the History API you also need to make sure that you server returns the Ember application under each one of those routes if the user enters the route directly.

For example if you type in your address bar 'domain/beers/all' the server should return your Ember application and Ember will figure out what to display.

Note that the History API is not available in some older browsers. You can check this at http://caniuse.com/history

Comment: Right. Then without using History API, with the first code only, it should not work?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: it seems that the code is correct, however, can not access domain /beers/all

Comment: When you say 'cannot access' do you mean you can't transition there inside your app or it doesn't work when you type it into your browser address bar?

Comment: Here the error on try access: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6730822/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-15%20at%206.04.29%20PM.png

Comment: Well yes, that's what I addressed in my answer. Your server will need to respond to all those routes with the Ember application. Are you using Ruby on Rails?

Comment: I am not using Ruby on Rails (yet). I just running it with: python -m SimpleHTTPServer, maybe this be the problem...

Comment: Not necessarily, you just have to configure your server to respond with your Ember application when you request it from sub-routes such as /beers/all. I'm afraid I can't help you with that though

Comment: Right, no problem. I Will try figure out how do this. Thanks

Comment: No problem - good luck! Since the above way explains how this is done in Ember, do you mind marking the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create those routes as folders, and place your index.html file in all of them.

You don't need any other files in these folders, since the index.html-file contains a "base href"-tag, so that the other files can be found.